# на minSdkVersion падает приложение

Tags: android, kotlin

Писал приложение и оно нормально работало на Android 8.0
Решил протестировать на минимальной версии (Android 4.1)
и у меня просто приложение падает

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:491)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule.provideRetrofit(NetworkModule.kt:24)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.provideRetrofit(NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:35)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:26)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:10)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.java:27)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.modules.NetworkModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.java:10)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.components.DaggerAppComponent.getAlbumRemoteDataSource(DaggerAppComponent.java:56)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.components.DaggerAppComponent.getAlbumRepository(DaggerAppComponent.java:59)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.components.DaggerAppComponent.getMainViewModelFactory(DaggerAppComponent.java:68)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.components.DaggerAppComponent.injectAlbumListFragment(DaggerAppComponent.java:89)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.di.components.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:82)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.ui.album_list.AlbumListFragment.onCreate(AlbumListFragment.kt:36)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:270)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1173)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2222)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1951)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2621)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:336)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1186)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Но я так и не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: Какая версия retrofit подключена?

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon 2.7.0

Comment: retrofit 2.7.0+ работает только на android 5.0+

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon тогда для чего это строчка на их сайте?

Comment: Retrofit requires at minimum Java 7 or Android 2.3.

Comment: Или есть где нибудь информация, какая версия Retrofit поддерживается в Android 4.1

Comment: видимо забыли обновить, посмотрите на github, там написано Retrofit requires at minimum Java 8+ or Android API 21+, просто понизьте версию до 2.6.4 https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778644/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-util-objects

Вот тут ответ на ваш вопрос есть. Ищите эти методы и обрамляйте if-ами